# Undefined with fs.createReadStream

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]

I'm working through the tutorial https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-nodejs-with-node-csv/ . Based on this in index.js I have:

```
const {parse} = require('csv-parse');
console.log(__dirname);
console.log(fs.readdirSync(__dirname));
var parser = parse({ columns: true }, function (err, records) {
    console.log(records);
});
const path =__dirname+'/file1.csv';
console.log(path);

var rs = fs.createReadStream(path);
rs.on('open', function () {
console.log('The file is open');
});

fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/file1.csv').pipe(parser);
```

Running with node gives:

```
.....
.....
/home/username/node/mydir/file1.csv
The file is open
undefined
```

The file path looks ok. What am I doing wrong?

Edit 1:

```
var parser = parse({ columns: true }, function (err, records) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(records);
});
```

Edit 2:

I ended up changing the code to :

```
var parser = parse({
columns: true, relax_column_count: true, skip_empty_lines:true, skip_records_with_error:true
}, function (err, records) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(records);
});
```

and the parsing started working.

Comment: Why do you create a read stream twice? On `var rs = fs.createReadStream(path)` and `fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/file1.csv').pipe(parser)`

Comment: Thats not the problem , I added the var.rs = ... part after, to test the file path

Comment: I also see that you're only checking `records` in your parser callback function. Is there any value returned to `err`?

Comment: You are right - I changed the code to Edit 1. Now getting: CsvError: Invalid Opening Quote: a quote is found inside a field at line 3187. So it must be a bad record