# Using async/await syntax with node stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

[image]

I'm using node 18.7 on ubuntu. I'm trying to parse a bunch of csv files to objects (using csv-parse), ultimately to load into a db.  Because there are large numbers of these I decided to try streams and I'd like to use the async await style.

So far I have:

```
const { parse } = require('csv-parse');
const path = __dirname + '/file1.csv';
const opt = { columns: true, relax_column_count: true, skip_empty_lines: true, skip_records_with_error: true };
console.log(path);
const { pipeline } = require('stream');
// const pipeline  = stream.pipeline;


async function readByLine(path, opt) {
    const readFileStream = fs.createReadStream(path);
    var csvParser = parse(opt, function (err, records) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    await pipeline(readFileStream, csvParser, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Pipeline failed.', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
        }
    });
    for await (const record of csvParser) {
        console.log(record);
    }
}

readByLine(path, opt)
```

When I run this I see:

```
Pipeline succeeded.
```

But the parsed objects are not sent to the console. What am I doing wrong?

edit1:

I changed the code to :

```
async function readByLine(path, opt) {
    const readFileStream = fs.createReadStream(path);
    var csvParser = parse(opt, function (err, records) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    await pipeline(readFileStream, csvParser, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Pipeline failed.', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
        }
    });
    // for await (const record of csvParser) {
    //     console.log(record);
    // }
    return csvParser;
}

(async function () {
    const o = await readByLine(path, opt);
    console.log(o);
})();
```

The result is an object which has a million properties, but some look set like in the screenshot.

Comment: How do you know if the objects were really parsed?

Comment: The code is based on working code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73256575/undefined-with-fs-createreadstream. What would you suggest to test further?

Comment: Making `readByLine` return `csvParser`. Calling this function with `await` before it. Then, assigning its return to a variable and finally logging the result.

Comment: return csvParser before or after the 'await pipeline..' block?

Comment: I meant after. To remove the `for await` and return something from the `async` which will be wrapped to a Promise, in order to observe the output.

Comment: please see edit

Answer (score 1):

You can only useful `await` a promise.

The `pipeline` function you are using doesn't return a promise.

If you [look at the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streampipelinesource-transforms-destination-callback) you will see:

> The pipeline API provides a promise version, which can also receive an options argument as the last parameter with a signal `<AbortSignal>` property. When the signal is aborted, destroy will be called on the underlying pipeline, with an AbortError.
>
> ```
> const { pipeline } = require('node:stream/promises');
> const fs = require('node:fs');
> const zlib = require('node:zlib');
>
> async function run() {
>   await pipeline(
>     fs.createReadStream('archive.tar'),
>     zlib.createGzip(),
>     fs.createWriteStream('archive.tar.gz')
>   );
>   console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
> }
>
> run().catch(console.error);
> ```

Note the different value passed to `require`. Use that version of `pipeline` instead.