# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] with node pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I'm using node 18.7 on ubuntu. I'm trying to parse a bunch of csv files to objects (using csv-parse), ultimately to load into a db.  Because there are large numbers of these I decided to try streams and I'd like to use the async await style.

Based on [Using async/await syntax with node stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73262986/using-async-await-syntax-with-node-stream/73263715#73263715) , I have changed my code to

```
   const { parse } = require('csv-parse');
const path = __dirname + '/file1.csv';
const opt = { columns: true, relax_column_count: true, skip_empty_lines: true, skip_records_with_error: true };
console.log(path);
const { pipeline } = require('node:stream/promises');

 async function readByLine(path, opt) {
    const readFileStream = fs.createReadStream(path);
    const writeFileStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/file2');
    var csvParser = parse(opt, function (err, records) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
   await pipeline(readFileStream, csvParser, writeFileStream);

}

readByLine(path, opt);
```

when I run the file, I'm getting:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Object
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:315:13)
at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
at Parser.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:766:22)
at Parser.emit (node:events:513:28)
at Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:539:10)
at Parser.<anonymous> (/home/gmail-username/node/maricopa/node_modules/csv-parse/dist/cjs/index.cjs:1357:28)
at Parser.emit (node:events:513:28)
at emitReadable_ (node:internal/streams/readable:590:12)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What format do you want the objects written as? in file2.

Comment: Json, since the idea is to parse csv into objects using csv-parse

Comment: @Matt, how did you the csvParser stream is in object mode?

Comment: The error, `The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Object` is the standard type of error you get in stream mismatch situation. Then in the pipeline `fs.read/parse/fs.write` the parse step is the only place that would occur as `fs.read/fs.write` are buffers/strings.

Comment: Here is the [csv-parse transform](https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv/blob/8ed0e186c9422ba5238b9e9c4adb9e94f8be4332/packages/csv-parse/lib/index.js#L16)

Comment: @Matt, One more (pretty dumb) question about streams in general. Adding a listener function does not modify the stream , correct?

Comment: It's not impossible, technically reading from a stream modifies it. Probably needs a specific question with example to answer as it's likely specific to the implementation of the stream .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reads from the `csvParser` stream](https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv/blob/8ed0e186c9422ba5238b9e9c4adb9e94f8be4332/packages/csv-parse/lib/index.js#L16) are in [object mode](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/stream.html#object-mode).

An [fs.writeStream](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/fs.html#class-fswritestream) requires strings/buffers to be written to it.

A simple [transform stream](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/stream.html#implementing-a-transform-stream) can be implemented to convert the objects to a JSON string by setting the `writableObjectMode` option:

```
class JsonTransform extends Transform {
    constructor(opt) {
        super(Object.assign({}, { writableObjectMode: true }, opt));
    }
    _transform(obj, enc, callback) {
        let ret = JSON.stringify(obj) + '\n'
        this.push(ret)
        callback()
    }
}
```

Then use that between the parse + file write.

```
const toJSON = new JsonTransform()
await pipeline(readFileStream, csvParser, toJSON, writeFileStream);
```

I believe the csv stringify project is similar for writing CSV's.